# How can I print/display the "User Principal Name" or UPN of a "p12" certificate on Linux?

Tags: linux, certificate

My company sent me a certificate for my smart phone. The file name is "3274634.p12". The documentation says "Enter your User Principal Name (UPN) as login" and it describes how to get this value using Internet Explorer.

How can I do the same on Linux (Kubuntu 13.04)?

Comment: There is by default no "UPN" or "User Principal Name" defined in a PKCS#12 file. Can you tell us how this works in IE perhaps then anyone can tell you how to do it on linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The PKCS#12 file usually contains a X.509 certificate and its associated private key. All information is stored in the certificate, so you need to extract it first:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -out foo.pem
```

(`foo.pem` will contain both the certificate *and* the private key.)

The UPN is stored as a special type of "subjectAltName" in the certificate. Unfortunately, OpenSSL does not yet know how to display UPNs (as well as some other types of names), so the usual command for examining certificates (`openssl x509 -noout -text < foo.pem`) will not work. Instead, you'll need low-level tools.

Separate the certificate to a file of its own (you can also do this with a text editor):

```
openssl x509 < foo.pem > foo.cert
```

Print the certificate as an ASN.1 structure:

```
openssl asn1parse -i -dump < foo.cert
```

Find the lines that describe the subjectAltName extension:

```
742:d=4  hl=3 l= 200 cons:     SEQUENCE          
745:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT          :X509v3 Subject Alternative Name
750:d=5  hl=3 l= 192 prim:      OCTET STRING    [HEX DUMP]:3081BDA036...
```

And run `asn1parse` again, this time telling it to dig deeper into the extension's contents (which are a yet another ASN.1 structure) – in this example, the value ("OCTET STRING" line) starts at offset 750:

```
openssl asn1parse -i -dump -strparse 750 < foo.cert
```

Finally, look for the UPN in the dump:

```
59:d=1  hl=2 l=  40 cons:  cont [ 0 ]        
61:d=2  hl=2 l=  10 prim:   OBJECT          :Microsoft Universal Principal Name
73:d=2  hl=2 l=  26 cons:   cont [ 0 ]        
75:d=3  hl=2 l=  24 prim:    UTF8STRING      :grawity@NULLROUTE.EU.ORG
```

---

If you have GnuTLS tools installed, there is a faster way but not as reliable. Once you have the certificate extracted, you can feed it to `certtool -i < foo.cert`, and it will print the raw contents even of names it doesn't recognize:

```
Subject Alternative Name (not critical):
    otherName OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3
    otherName DER: 0c1867726177697479404e554c4c524f5554452e45552e4f5247
    otherName ASCII: ..grawity@NULLROUTE.EU.ORG
```

Look for the OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3`; it will be followed by the name's raw contents. Luckily, they consist of a single UTF8String, so the "otherName ASCII" output is easily understood – just strip the first two bytes (shown as dots here).

---

A simpler way would be to just try entering your own Windows login; the UPN is always in the form `username@domain`.

(It's a bit sad that out of all tools I've tried, almost none of them know how to interpret such simple and commonly used – even if proprietary – name types.)

Comment: Whow ... complicated but it works. Just one thing. It prints `:name@domain`. I guess the colon can/must be ignored?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Yes, the colon is just part of asn1parse output. The UPN is always `name@domain`.

Comment: [dumpasn1](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dumpasn1.1.html) might also be worth trying. I haven't yet tried it on certificate with UPN, but its config file does include "OID = 1 3 6 1 4 1 311 20 2 3
Comment = Microsoft UPN
Description = universalPrincipalName"

Answer (score 0):

Building on the excellent answer of [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity),

If you just want to copy the SAN from another certificate, you can copy the whole ASN.1 SAN sub-structure.

Find the lines that describe the subjectAltName extension:

```
742:d=4  hl=3 l= 200 cons:     SEQUENCE          
745:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT          :X509v3 Subject Alternative Name
750:d=5  hl=3 l= 192 prim:      OCTET STRING    [HEX DUMP]:3081BDA036...
```

And paste the hex string into the openssl config:

```
 [v3_extensions_section]
 subjectAltName = DER:3081BDA036...
```

I expect any other extension that appears as "[HEX DUMP]" in the asn1parse output can be copied too.